# Loading spinner as well as fetched products from firebase isn't showing until I refresh the screen in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using ActivityIndicator for showing the loading screen while my dispatch function dispatches the action and fetches the products from the firebase and renders it on my app screens But this is not happening. My app is showing products that are in store as dummy data and if I refresh the screen then it shows the data from firebase but not the loading spinner to show that loading is true.

ProductOverviewScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";

import ProductItem from "../../components/shop/ProductItem";
import * as cartActions from "../../store/actions/cart";
import * as productActions from "../../store/actions/products";
import CustomHeaderButton from "../../components/UI/HeaderButton";
import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";

const ProductOverviewScreen = (props) => {
  const [IsLoading, setIsLoading] = useState();
  const [IsRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.availableProducts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const loadedProducts = useCallback(() => {
    setError(null);
    setIsRefreshing(true);
    dispatch(productActions.fetchProducts())
      .then(setIsLoading(false))
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message);
      });
    setIsRefreshing(false);
  }, [dispatch, setIsLoading, setError]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const willFocusSub = props.navigation.addListener(
      "willFocus",
      loadedProducts
    );
    return () => {
      willFocusSub.remove();
    };
  }, [loadedProducts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loading = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      await loadedProducts();
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
  }, [dispatch, loadedProducts]);

  const selectItemHandler = (id, title) => {
    props.navigation.navigate("ProductDetail", {
      productId: id,
      productTitle: title,
    });
  };

  const addToCartHandler = async (itemData) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await dispatch(cartActions.addToCart(itemData.item));
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  if (error) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loadingSpiner}>
        <Text>An Error occurred! </Text>
        <Button
          title="Try Again"
          onPress={loadedProducts}
          color={Colors.primary}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (IsLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loadingSpiner}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Colors.primary} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (!IsLoading && products.length === 0) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loadingSpiner}>
        <Text>No Product Found!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={products}
      onRefresh={loadedProducts}
      refreshing={IsRefreshing}
      renderItem={(itemData) => (
        <ProductItem
          image={itemData.item.imageUrl}
          title={itemData.item.title}
          price={itemData.item.price}
          onSelect={() => {
            selectItemHandler(itemData.item.id, itemData.item.title);
          }}
        >
          <Button
            color={Colors.primary}
            title="View Details"
            onPress={() => {
              selectItemHandler(itemData.item.id, itemData.item.title);
            }}
          />
          {IsLoading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="small" color={Colors.primary} />
          ) : (
            <Button
              color={Colors.primary}
              title="To Cart"
              onPress={() => {
                addToCartHandler(itemData);
              }}
            />
          )}
        </ProductItem>
      )}
    />
  );
};

ProductOverviewScreen.navigationOptions = (navigationData) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: "All Products",
    headerLeft: () => (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title="Menu"
          iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-menu" : "ios-menu"}
          color={Platform.OS === "android" ? Colors.primary : "white"}
          onPress={() => {
            navigationData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
          }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    ),
    headerRight: () => (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title="Cart"
          iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-cart" : "ios-cart"}
          onPress={() => {
            navigationData.navigation.navigate("Cart");
          }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    ),
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loadingSpiner: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    opacity: 1,
  },
});

export default ProductOverviewScreen;
```

I have also checked on both emulators IOS and android also on my real device. If I open the app on my real device then instantly app renders the data from the firebase but doesn't show a loading spinner.

In useEffect If I try to add dependency `loading` which costs async code and a function which fetches the data from firebase then it shows an error saying `Can't find variable: loading`.

Comment: `loadedProducts` isn't an `async` function nor does it return a Promise so it can't be `await`ed on. The `isLoading` state is updated twice and the second one setting it back to false.

Comment: Can you please mention where I have to make changes in isLoading?

Comment: Set `isLoading` true in `loadedProducts` right before the dispatch. When the promise chain resolves it sets it back false.

Comment: But I have already set `isLoading` to true in `loading` before calling the `loadedProducts`.

Comment: Do the above and just call `loadedProducts();` in the `useEffect`, no need for the `loading` function.

Comment: But I have added `loading` for setting refreshing state and loading state. See in `loadedProducts` I have added`setIsRefreshing` for refreshing the screen when the user scrolls down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234976/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-harsh-mishra).

Answer (score 0):

Please making loadedProducts from sync to async